# EmberJS, How to manage different "config variables" for different "environments"

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, environments, ember.js-2

There are several of questions under the *emberjs* tag that talk about how to manage different *environments* but all of them are only applying for very concrete scenarios.

I'm looking for a general solution of how to set different **config variables** for different **environments**.

Let's say of example I have one API URL for my *develoment* environment and another API URL for my *production* environment.

```
production_api_url: "http://production.server.com/api"
development_api_url: "http://development.server.com/api"
```

And in my *adapter* I would like to use the appropriate API URL:

```
# /app/adapters/application.js
import ActiveModelAdapter from 'active-model-adapter';

export default ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',
  host: [[API_URL]]
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ember 2.2 and EmberCLI it can work out-of-the-box like this:

Setting up the URLS for each *environment*:

```
# /config/environments.js
...
if (production === 'production') {
  ENV.API_HOST = 'http://production.server.com'
}

if (environment === 'development') {
  ENV.API_HOST = 'http://development.server.com'
}
...
```

Using the URL in the *adapter*:

```
# /app/adapters/application.js
import ActiveModelAdapter from 'active-model-adapter';
import config from '../config/environment';

export default ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',
  host: config.API_HOST
});
```